# JWPlayer cannot play mp4 link: Error loading player: No playable sources found

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I've try to make the direct url of Google Video to work with JWPlayer but always get the error:

> Error loading player: No playable sources found.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "https://r6---sn-i3b7sney.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=2b899e7ff80b620f&itag=18&source=webdrive&app=docs&ip=27.0.15.249&ipbits=0&expire=1425971365&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=9AAFD9BB484907A6955AA71C68681E81A9E2C0A.AB4113F235720EF4796D58AA422A3FC8EE68B822&key=ck2&mm=30&ms=nxu&mt=1425967720&mv=m&pl=24&type=video/mp4;%20codecs=%22avc1.42001E,%20mp4a.40.2%22&quality=medium",
        width: 320,
        height: 200,
        primary: 'flash',
        type: 'mp4'
    });
</script>
```

Note: I've try that url with default html5 video tag, it's work well, even with videojs, work well too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google Video is not supported.

We only support the following:

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support

The only 3rd party source we support is YouTube, via their API.

Comment: I don't think the problem is JWPlayer support Google Video or not, let talk it's a normal streaming mp4 path, my question is why it's can normal play with html5 video tag, other flash video player also normal too. So why JWPlayer not? Just because I think JWPlayer is the best player at currently so I cannot give up on it.

Comment: Yes it is exactly that. Also https://r6---sn-i3b7sney.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=2b899e7ff80b620f&itag=18&source=webdrive&app=docs&ip=27.0.15.249&ipbits=0&expire=1425971365&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=9AAFD9BB484907A6955AA71C68681E81A9E2C0A.AB4113F235720EF4796D58AA422A3FC8EE68B822&key=ck2&mm=30&ms=nxu&mt=1425967720&mv=m&pl=24&type=video/mp4;%20codecs=%22avc1.42001E,%20mp4a.40.2%22&quality=medium has expired now, so using direct Google Video links is not a sustainable solution. Unsupported.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah, sure that my demo link has expired, because it's rendered and only live in 1 hour, the "sustabinable" can be handle at user side, the main is JWPlayer cannot play that url even it's live, I'm switch to use the VideoJS with really amazing support and streaming from Google Video link, the link can expired but it't easy to get new link and continue playing :). Anyway, my suggest is JWPlayer should support streaming from that link, because you make the bussiness, I plan to buy the JWPlayer pre to use on my site but I think I'll wait more and more time :)

Comment: We are not going to plan on supporting any other 3rd party source other than YouTube, I'm afraid. My answer is correct, we don't support it.

Comment: No, it's not correct, what happen if I create my own streaming server which the same with the way of Google, and then it's become 3rd, and you can't support it? Anyway, if you said that you have no plan with it so I'll give up on JW and switch to VideoJS. Goodbye!

Comment: Of course we can support your own streaming server. Google Video isn't supported by us. Bottom line.

Answer (score 0):

That is because google video expires in certain period,
use a php script to generate video's link.

**Update:** I remember once even I tried docs.google.com videos, but it didn't worded with jw player. So, instead I used googlevideo.com.